# Capturing An AppleEvent in Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, unity-game-engine

Ok Unity3d allows you to set your external script editor in the application preferences. So I want to use applescript to launch my own editor. This applescript has worked pretty well for me so far but I have been unable to jump to the line number.

According to Unity the "line number should be sent through a parameter in an AppleEvent. It should be of typeChar and of keyAEPosition ('kpos') The structure sent through this parameter has the following layout:"

```
struct TheSelectionRange 
{
    short unused1; // 0 (not used)
    short lineNum; // line to select (<0 to specify range)
    long startRange; // start of selection range (if line < 0)
    long endRange; // end of selection range (if line < 0)
    long unused2; // 0 (not used)
    long theDate; // modification date/time
};
```

"lineNum should be populated with the correct line. The other fields will not be populated with anything than 0 and -1."

So how come I don't see any of this coming through my input? how do I capture this apple event?

My Script:

```
on run input
    set element to item 1 of input
    if (element is in {{}, {""}, ""}) then
        return
    else
        tell application "System Events"
            set ProcessList to name of every process
            if "iTerm" is in ProcessList then
                set iterm_running to true
            else
                set iterm_running to false
            end if
            log iterm_running
        end tell
        tell application "iTerm"
            activate
            if (count terminal) < 1 then
                set term to (make new terminal)
            else
                set term to current terminal
            end if
            tell term
                set create_session to false
                try
                    do shell script ("/usr/local/bin/vim --servername UNITY --remote-send ''")
                    set create_session to false
                on error errorMessage number errorNumber
                    set create_session to true
                end try

                if iterm_running then
                    if create_session then
                        launch session "Default Session"
                        activate current session
                        tell current session
                            set name to "Unity"
                            write text "/usr/local/bin/vim --servername UNITY --remote-silent \"$(echo \"/Volumes/" & input & "\" | tr : /)\""
                        end tell
                    else
                        do shell script ("/usr/local/bin/vim --servername UNITY --remote-silent \"$(echo \"/Volumes/" & input & "\" | tr : /)\"")
                    end if
                else
                    activate current session
                    tell current session
                        set name to "Unity"
                        write text "/usr/local/bin/vim --servername UNITY --remote-silent \"$(echo \"/Volumes/" & input & "\" | tr : /)\""
                    end tell
                end if
            end tell
        end tell
    end if
    return input
end run
```

Answer (score 0):

If you handle the open event, you should see some parameters, including the line number:

```
on open (x,y)
  display dialog x
  display dialog y
  -- use x and y in your own script
end open
```